# Where can I find in the Standard a reference to the equivalence between *p and p[0], *(p+1) and p[1], ...?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

In the snippet below, the notation `*p` is equivalent to `p[0]`, `*(p + 1)` is equivalent to `p[1]`, and so on.

```
int* p = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3};
cout << *p << ' ' << *(p + 1) << ' ' << *(p + 2) << '\n';
cout << p[0] << ' ' << p[1] << ' ' << p[2] << '\n';
```

Where in the Standard can I find some reference to this equivalence?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the draft C++14 standard section 5.2.1 Subscripting [expr.sub] (*emphasis mine*):

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions
>   shall have the type “array of T” or “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration
>   or integral type.[...] **The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))** [ Note: see 5.3 and 5.7 for details of * and
>   + and 8.3.4 for details of arrays. —end note ],

This paragraph references section `5.3` for `*` which says:

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an
>   object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function
>   to which the expression points. If the type of the expression is “pointer to T,” the type of the result is
>   “T.”[...]

and section `5.7` for `+` which says:

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type
>   of the pointer operand. [...] if
>   the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P))
>   and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i + n-th and i − n-th elements of the array
>   object, provided they exist[ ...]

Comment: So this is why `a[1]` <=> `1[a]` as `*((a)+(1))` <=> `*((1)+(a))`

Answer (score 2):

C++14:

**5.2.1 Subscripting**

The relevant part:

> 1 ... The
>   expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))` ...

**5.3.1 Unary operators**

The relevant part:

> 1 The unary `*` operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an
>   object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function
>   to which the expression points. If the type of the expression is “pointer to `T`,” the type of the result is
>   “`T`.” ...

**5.7 Additive operators**

The relevant part:

> 5 ... In other words, if
>   the expression `P` points to the *i*-th element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently, `N+(P)`)
>   and `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value *n*) point to, respectively, the *i + n*-th and *i − n*-th elements of the array
>   object, provided they exist. ...

Comment: I'm accepting Shafik's answer. He beat you by just a few seconds. Thanks.